# Defining drop rules for Jquery UI Sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some lists with some nested elements. With JQuery UI sortables I can drag and drop and run background calls to save sort orders.

It has now become necessary to elaborate on the basic sorting and define some rules.

I can get part way there but am now unable to get quite there.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPQZx/590/)

The rules I wish to establish are:

1. Recipes can only be sorted up and down within the top level list and cannot be dropped into a section
2. Sections can only be sorted up and down within the top level list and cannot be nested into a section
3. Ingredients can be  sorted up and down within the top level list and can be dropped into a section
4. Section ingredients can be sorted up and down within the section and, section ingredients can be dragged out into the top level list. Once in the top level list they can be dragged back to a section (or from one section to another)

Here is what I have:

```
<div>
<ul class="isort rsort ssort">
    <li class="recipe" >Recipe 1</li>
     <li class="section">Section
        <ul class="isort">
            <li class="ingredient" >Ingredient A</li>
            <li class="ingredient">Ingredient B</li>
            <li class="ingredient">Ingredient C</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="ingredient">Ingredient 1</li>
     <li class="ingredient">Ingredient 2</li>
     <li class="recipe" >Recipe 2</li>
      <li class="section">Section 2
        <ul class="isort">
            <li class="ingredient" >Ingredient D</li>
            <li class="ingredient">Ingredient E</li>
            <li class="ingredient">Ingredient F</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

```
$("ul.isort").sortable({
    items: '.ingredient',
    connectWith: "ul.isort",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(evt, ui) {
     //alert('dropping i sort');
    }
}); 

$("ul.rsort, ul.ssort").sortable({
    items: '.recipe,.section',
    connectWith: "ul > li > ul > li",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(evt, ui) {
     //alert('dropping s and r sort');
    }
});
```

As you can see I can do most of it aside from dragging top level ingredients into sections. Also, it appears once an ingredient is dropped, it sometimes is unable to be moved on again. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

After much puzzling and reviewing the docs and other questions on here I came up with this solution there is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnyLk4rb/48/). Items dragged to dis-allowed drop lists are returned to their original places.

```
(function($) {

$('.sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: 'ul',
  items: "li",
  beforeStop: function(evt, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('recipe') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
    }
    if ($(ui.item).hasClass('section') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
    }
  },
  update: function(evt, ui) {
      alert('landed');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);

HTML:

<ul id="main" class="sortable">
  <li id="item1" class="ingredient">Ingredient 0.1</li>
  <li id="item2" class="ingredient">Ingredient 0.2</li>
  <li id="item3" class="section">Section 1
    <ul id="sub1">
      <li id="item31" class="ingredient">Ingredient 1.1</li>
      <li id="item32" class="ingredient">Ingredient 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="item4" class="section">Section 2
    <ul id="sub2">
      <li id="item41" class="ingredient">Ingredient 2.1</li>
      <li id="item42" class="ingredient">Ingredient 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="item5" class="recipe">Recipe 0.1</li>
  <li id="item6" class="recipe">Recipe 0.2</li>
</ul>
```